# jQuery, failed to change attribute checked on checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have some problem with checkboxes and changing its state by JavaScript and jQuery.

When I try to change attribute "checked" by this jQuery code, its works perfectly:

```
jQuery("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", false);
```

But, if I need change attribute by specific attribute it doesn't work (attribute changed, by checkbox is still select):

```
jQuery("#id").prop("checked", false);
```

How can I change "checked" attribute by ID?

Comment: does that id exist and is it unique..?

Comment: IDs may be of asp.net server controls! Is It?

Comment: when you change the checked state of a checkbox... the attribute is not changed instead an internal property of the dom element is changed

Comment: Did you checked your console log for errors.

Comment: Post your markup or a fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This,

```
$('input[type='checkbox'][value='value_to_be_checked']').prop('checked',true);
```

Mention value of checkbox to be checked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `prop` like the following fiddle : `http://jsfiddle.net/3qp99/1/`

Answer (score 0):

Try simpley with it (If you want a pure JS solution without using jQuery)

```
document.getElementById("myId").checked = true; // check
document.getElementById("myId").checked = false; //uncheck
```